# dynamically parse json message to poco object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this method that parses a json reponse message to a specific poco object.

Is it possible to change it in a way that I add a classtype at runtime and use this method for multiple classes.

```
private static async Task<TestClass> ParseResponseMessageToObject(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
{
    if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) { return null; }

    using (Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        return (TestClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd(), typeof(TestClass));
    }
}
```

Comment: try make this method generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
private static async Task<T> ParseResponseMessageToObject<T>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
{
    if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) { return default(T); }

    using (Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

If the type you use is not known at compile time, you can use *dynamic*

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
int i = dynObj.SomeIntProperty
```

Since JObject implements IDictionary, you can also use it as

```
var  dynObj = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
int i = (int)dynObj["SomeIntProperty"];
```

Comment: Thanks that was easier then I thought. I thought i had to pass the type of object or something like that.

Comment: Would this also work for a list of objects by replacing T with List<T>?

Comment: Nevermind I found the return type is Task<List<T>> but the  class specification after the method name stays <T>.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your method to be more generic like this

```
private static async Task<T> ParseResponseMessageToObject<T>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : class, new()
    {
        if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) { return null; }

        using (Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd(), typeof(T));
        }
    }
```